How to fix google app script permissions popup
We've written some custom app-script that is on a google sheet. The script was 'deployed as a webapp'. The document is a template, that we want teams to use. So each team is being asked to make a copy, and populate. However every single time that happens the new users are receiving the following prompt:

This is undesirable, we put a lot of time into training our employees not to click random permissions, and honestly even for a savy users there is not enough information for them to make an informed decision.
Our org is on gsuite, is there a way to register or approve an appscript at the org level as trusted?
Note: before we deployed it as a webapp, users would get a different popup asking for permission to their entire gdrive, which was even worse. Deploying as a webapp seemes to have reduced the prompt.
Note2: I'm open to deploying it differently too. The functionality is when they press a button, it does a bunch of custom data manipulation then puts it all back in the table.

Briefly, what you are looking for requires the creation of a Google Cloud platform project to create a service account and set it with "domain-wide delegation of authority".
You Will need help from the Google Workspace administrator of your company.
This implies redesigning your "some custom app scripts." To learn why, please read Authorization for Google Services.
Resources

Assign permissions for Google Cloud projects

Related

Delegate domain wide authority for a script bound to Google Forms
How to perform G Suite domain-Wide delegation of authority without user intervention?

